# Attach an AWS IAM Role to an Existing Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: terraform

i am trying to crate one new s3 bucket  using terraform and want to access from existing ec2 instance. How can i do using terraform.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an s3 bucket would be an easy task with terraform so you can use the following stanza. You can refer to more from [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket).

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "mybucket" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  tags = {
    Name        = "My bucket"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}
```

Then we need to create an IAM role. Piece of cake!

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
  name = "test_role"

  # Terraform's "jsonencode" function converts a
  # Terraform expression result to valid JSON syntax.
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    <<<add your policy here >>>
})

  tags = {
    tag-key = "tag-value"
  }
}
```

Please change the stanza accordingly.

Okay then we need to create an instance profile, then the role can be assigned to the ec2 instance.

```
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "test_profile" {
  name = "test_profile"
  role = aws_iam_role.test_role.name
}
```

If the ec2 instance is not created by Terraform, then comes the problem. If so you need to import the resource to your state file. Follow the terraform command to import the ec2 instance to the state file.

```
terraform import aws_instance.web <instance_id>
```

Now you have imported the instance to the state file, but still, it's not in the terraform configuration. So now you need to write the configuration manually. Then try to run `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` to see the import is correctly done.

Then you can add the role to the ec2 instance.

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami = "xxxxxx"
  instance_type = "xxxxx"
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.test_profile.name
  ...
}
```

If your ec2 is already created by terraform you just need to add `iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.test_profile.name` in the `aws_instance` resource block.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a `IAM role` follow this [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role) for more instructions and examples. Basically you need `name` and `assume role` parameters. The `assumes role` means on what services will the given role have effects.

Next you need to create policies follow this [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_policy) for more on that. You can create your own policies or use the existing ones.

Next you need to attach the policies to the role. Link [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_policy_attachment).

And finally in order to attach it to ec2 instance you need to create `instance profile` which you can find [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_instance_profile). It's pretty straight forward you just need to specify the name and the role which you want to attach to `instance profile`.

And finally in your `aws instance` section where you create ec2 instance you need to specify the following paramter `iam_instance_profile: <your instance profile name>`

If you need additional help feel free to comment and I will try to help you but I think the wiki pages I gave you here are pretty good and explain stuff well enough.